# How to solve the ODE $\frac{y}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{e^{x}}{\ln y}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks me to solve at $y(1)=1$,

$$\frac{y}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{e^{x}}{\ln y}$$

The answer somehow gets to
$$
\frac{1}{2}y^{2}\ln y -\frac{1}{4}y^{2}=4xe^{x}-4e^{x}-1.
$$
I have figured out that if I rewrite the original equation like 
$$
y\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{xe^x}{\ln y}.
$$
I can rewrite the $y (dy/dx)$ as
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left [ \frac{1}{2}y^2 \right],
$$
but this is where I get stuck. I can't do anything else to it and integrating the other side seems iffy to me with the $x$ and $y$ together. I know the principles of integration with mixed variables, it just doesn't yield the correct answer. I have gone in circles for a few hours now and I would like to understand how it works.

Comment: Separate the variables. All $x$'s on one side, with $dx$ and all $y$'s on the other side, with $dy$, then integrate both sides.

Comment: This title should become a meme. Sadly, this website is not meme friendly :O

Comment: The answer is wrong on the LHS it should be $$2y^{2}\ln y -y^{2}=4xe^{x}-4e^{x}-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is separable.

$$ \int_1^y \eta \ln \eta \, d\eta = \int_1^x \xi \, e^\xi \,  d\xi$$

Integrate by parts on the left hand and right hand sides.

$$\int_1^y \ln \eta \, d \left( \frac{\eta^2}{2} \right) = \int_1^x \xi d e^\xi$$

$$\frac{y^2}{2}\ln y - \int_1^y \frac{\eta}{2} \, d\eta = xe^x-e - \int_1^x e^\xi d\xi$$

$$\frac{y^2}{2}\ln y -\frac{y^2}{4} +\frac{1}{4}=xe^x - e^x $$

Comment: I suppose I took it for granted that (variable)ln(variable) cannot be integrated with respect to that variable because I was trying to do that before in my spare time and I got an infinite integration by parts.

Comment: What's an infinite integration by parts?  You took some other choice for $u$ and $v$ in the formula $\int u dv = uv - v\int du$?

Comment: I was bored and tried integrating x^x but it kept expanding to show e^x being a factor if done infinitely.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like the solutions that people came up with are all more or less the same.  You can solve the problem using indefinite integration, and then plug in the initial values to get the constant of integration, or you can use definite integration.  Either way, it seems that integration by parts is the straight path to the solution.  Of course, to get there, you need to recognize that you need to arrive at one side of the equation in terms of $x$ and the other in terms of $y.$

Comment: Must have made a mistake. Probably tired whilst doing it, lol. Never do this shit while impaired you get bad stuff. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{y}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{e^{x}}{\ln y}$$
The differential equation is separable:
$${y \ln y }{dy}= {xe^{x}}dx$$
$$\int {y \ln y }{dy}=\int {xe^{x}}dx$$
$$\int {y \ln y }{dy}= {xe^{x}}-e^x+c$$
integrate by part
$$\int y \ln y dy =\frac {y^2}{2}
 \ln y- \frac 12 \int y dy$$ 
$$\int y \ln y dy =\frac {y^2}{2}
 \ln y- \frac 14 y^2$$ 
Apply initial condition.
$$y(1)=1 \implies c=-\frac 14$$
The answer is wrong on the LHS it should be $$ \boxed {2y^{2}\ln y -y^{2}=4xe^{x}-4e^{x}-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is separation of variables...
$$  y \ln y \,\mathrm{d}y = x \mathrm{e}^x \,\mathrm{d}x  $$
Then \begin{align*}
\int y \ln y \,\mathrm{d}y &= \frac{y^2 \ln y}{2} - \int \frac{y \,\mathrm{d}y}{2} && \left[ \begin{matrix} u = \ln y & \mathrm{d}v = y\,\mathrm{d}y  \\
\mathrm{d}u = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} & v = y^2/2 \end{matrix}  \right.  \\
&= \frac{y^2 \ln y}{2} -\frac{y^2}{4} \ [{}+C]  \text{ and} \\
\int x \mathrm{e}^x \,\mathrm{d}x &= x \mathrm{e}^x - \int\mathrm{e}^x \,\mathrm{d}x && \left[ \begin{matrix} u = x & \mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{e}^x \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
\mathrm{d}u = \mathrm{d}x & v = \mathrm{e}^x\end{matrix} \right.  \\
&= x \mathrm{e}^x - \mathrm{e}^x \ [{}+C]  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Since the difference of two arbitrary constants is an arbitrary constant, we have
$$  \frac{y^2 \ln y}{2} -\frac{y^2}{4} = x \mathrm{e}^x - \mathrm{e}^x + C  \text{.}  $$
To meet the condition $y(1) = 1$, we must select the antiderivative where the constant of integration satisfies
$$  \frac{1^2 \ln 1}{2} -\frac{1^2}{4} = 1 \mathrm{e}^1 - \mathrm{e}^1 + C  \text{.}  $$
That is, $C = -1/4$.  So the particular solution is
$$  \frac{y^2 \ln y}{2} -\frac{y^2}{4} = x \mathrm{e}^x - \mathrm{e}^x - \frac{1}{4}  \text{.}  $$
Clearing denominators, 
$$  2y^2 \ln y - y^2 = 4 x \mathrm{e}^x - 4\mathrm{e}^x - 1 \text{.}  $$

Somehow, the given answer seems to be a splice of the last two displays.